# How to implement a timeout in open/write function

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fifo

I want to use named fifo channel and I want to implement a timeout when I write in this fifo.

```
fd = open(pipe, O_WRONLY);
write(fd, msg, len);
```

Program is blocked by function open, so using the function select will not work.
Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't `O_NONBLOCK` work?

Comment: I need block, but with timeout

Comment: I never did this, but could `inotify` + `select` to determine whether the FIFO is ready and then a pessimistic `open()` with `O_NONBLOCK` set possibly do the trick?

Comment: You need to have some process reading that pipe or FIFO. Do you have some? Read [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Comment: Why are you asking? What do you really want to do. What is the FIFO for? What is the process on the other side, and how does it start? Can you somehow improve the code on both sides?

Answer (score 2):

use `select()` and its timeout argument.

Comment: It won't work if it is the `open` syscall which is blocking (since both `select`  and `poll` need opened file descriptors)

Comment: Your `open` is blocked until some other process opens it in reading mode... Fifo is a communication object, so it is considered as a non-sense to let you try writing if there is no counterpart. You should have a reading part as basile said.

Answer (score 2):

Read [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

You might setup a timer or or alarm with a signal handler (see [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) & [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)) before your call to [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) - but I won't do that - or you could use the `O_NONBLOCK` flag, since `fifo(7)` says:

> ```
>  A process can open a FIFO in nonblocking mode.  In this case, opening
> for read-only will succeed even if no-one has opened on the write
> side yet, opening for write-only will fail with ENXIO (no such device
> or address) unless the other end has already been opened.
> ```

However, you need something (some other process reading) on the other side of the FIFO or pipe.

Perhaps you should consider using [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets, i.e. the `AF_UNIX` address family. It looks more relevant to your case: change your code above (trying to open for writing a FIFO) to a AF_UNIX socket on the client side (with a connect), and change the other process to become an AF_UNIX socket server.

As [5gon12eder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392132/5gon12eder) commented, you might also look into [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html). Or even perhaps [D-bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) !

<sup>I'm guessing that FIFOs or pipes are not the right solution in your situation. You should explain more and give a broader picture of your concerns and goals.</sup>